# How to create custom Table Layout with headers and grid lines

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I spent almost the whole weekend to figure out how to create a table structure with headers for columns and rows and include `ImageButtons` in the cells of the table. The grid lines should be visible.
I tried lot of different layouts... `Grid`, `Linear`, `Structured`, `CoordinatorLayout` .... view nested `GridViews` and so on. But couldn't figure out how to accomplish something like this?

Some kind of nested layout magic?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Start with adding your current layout and everything that you have done or you question will most likely won't get answered, it may even get closed for being "too broad"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a drawable `cell_shape.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape= "rectangle"  >

    <stroke android:width="0.5dp"  android:color="#4E4E4E"/>
</shape>
```

**In your styles.xml** define your custom cell style

```
 <style name="Cell">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/cell_shape</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
```

**table_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                style="@style/Cell"
                android:text="\"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/Cell"
                android:text="My Title 1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/Cell"
                android:text="My Title 2"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/Cell"
                android:text="My Title 3"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                style="@style/Cell"
                android:text="Arg 1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageButton
                style="@style/Cell"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageButton
                style="@style/Cell"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageButton
                style="@style/Cell"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </TableRow>
        <!--Next Rows...-->
    </TableLayout>
    <!--//..-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. That looks really good! Very promising and a great foundation to experiment a little further. Sorry for the lack of details within my description. Was my first post here. Best Regards!

Comment: @f0x  Accept the answer if this answered your question

Comment: Sorry, I just did :-)